# Page load on button click issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a button  when i click a button add country the page gets loaded and the modal popup disappears please help me to solve the issue.

```
 <form id="new" runat="server">
    <button id="Button2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" runat="server"   data-target="#DivCountry">Add Country</button>


     <div class="modal fade" id="DivCountry">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                                <div class="modal-header">

                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Country</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">                                
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">COUNTRY:</span>
                                    <input type="text" style="width:50%" id="txtcountry"  name="nmcountry" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Country" />
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="CountrySave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Which button do you mean? Is it the element with `id="DivCountry"` that becomes the modal popup? Do you have any code that makes any of that happen?

Comment: @Guffa When i click add country modal disappears after page load

Comment: sounds like some `If(IsPostBack)` issues at first glance..

Comment: It's just a button that posts the form. Where is the modal popup, and do you have any code for that? If the page reloads, do you have any code that would make the popup appear again?

Comment: @Guffa u can see the div tag that is the modal popup

Comment: @MethodMan how to solve the issue.

Comment: its pretty simple. if you invoke a client side modal popup and do a form submit, then it will of course disappear. you need to persist the state of the modal dialog and render it again if it was already opened. when you do a full postback, the state is essentially lost and re-written to the browser.

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas can u pls illustrate an example

Comment: I don't need to - you already have the example....

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'runat="server"' from the button. Your html is being over-written because the server is sending back a new page.